# web.config file in Cache Manifest not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, cache-manifest

I am using HTML5 cache manifest to build to be able to load some dynamic ASP.NET pages (text and images) from database even without internet connection.

All working fine when I list my connectionString as a string in the code behind (c#) but when I try to access it from the web.config file it does not work because the web.config file cannot be cached somehow. I am including it in the CACHE section of my manifest along with all the other files that are correctly being cached.

Can you cache the app.config file or is there some other work around please?

Answer (score 0):

The cache manifest has nothing to do with web.config.

Web.config is solely used by the server. The Cache Manifest is handled by the browser.

Your caching not working must have a different reason.

Comment: Thanks. So you cannot cache the app.config file then?

Comment: No, the "cache" is something the browser handles. The app.config is something from the server, the client has nothing to do with it.